# Create object templates (for e.g. EditorFor, etc) for MVC using code, not views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create EditorFor templates for a custom object using code only rather than a View template in the EditorTemplates.

My reason is so that I can create a class library with these templates.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create EditorFor templates for a custom object using
>   code only rather than a View template in the EditorTemplates.

Not unless you write your custom EditorFor helper. The standard helper looks for templates.

> My reason is so that I can create a class library with these templates

In this case you could [embed your templates into an assembly](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) as resources.

Comment: With writing a custom EditorFor - is that just a case of writing an extension method on HtmlHelper<TModel> taking an argument of type Expression<Func<TModel, MyCustomObject>> ? I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to be picked up as the 'closer' extension method to call, favouring the default EditorFor (which takes Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>) instead. If possible, I want the developer using my library to be able to use the standard EditorFor rather than a specific method - e.g. EditorForCustomObject.

Comment: I'll have a look at embedding the templates into the assembly - do you know if that will be picked up by EditorFor though?